# how to change name folder frontend and backend in yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Currently my url is `http://localhost/halodocnew/frontend/web/index.php?r=site%2Flogin` I want to change name folder `frontend` to `client`  for all action.

Please help me

Thank all so much

Comment: What are you using as Web server?

Comment: Best practies are to point document root directory in your web server to `web` directory inside your application. Because all of other directories of your project( controllers, models) should not have access from web

Answer (score 2):

Suppose you want to rename backend to admin the follow the following steps

1)Rename backend folder to admin

2)Update Bootstrap.php under common/config/Bootstrap.php

```
Yii::setAlias('@backend', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/backend');
```

To

```
Yii::setAlias('@admin', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/admin');
```

3)Update site controller namespace  under admin/controller/siteController.php  `backend\controllers;` to namespace `admin\controllers;`

4) Update main.php ubder admin/config 
`'controllerNamespace' => 'backend\controllers'` to `'controllerNamespace' => 'admin\controllers'`

Answer (score 1):

**For Quick solution:**

Copy and Paste your `frontend` folder in same directory and rename it to `client`

Open `halodocnew\common\config\bootstrap.php`

Add alias: `Yii::setAlias('client', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/client');`

Access in browser:
`http://localhost/halodocnew/client/web/index.php`

**Another Solution:**

- Go into `halodocnew\environments\dev\`
- Copy & Paste `frontend` in this folder and rename it to `client`.
- Then go to `halodocnew\environments\prod\`
- Copy & Paste `frontend` in this folder and rename it to `client`.
- Open `halodocnew\environments\index.php`
- Find `'Development' => [
      'path' => 'dev',
      'setWritable' => [
          'backend/runtime',
          'backend/web/assets',`
- Add `'Development' => [
      'path' => 'dev',
      'setWritable' => [
          'backend/runtime',
          'backend/web/assets',
          'client/runtime',
          'client/web/assets',`
- Do same above for  `'Production' => [
                        'path' => 'prod',`
- Go into your project root directory and run `php init`
- Copy `web` and `veiws` folder from `frontend` to `client`
- Open `halodocnew\common\config\bootstrap.php`
- Add alias: `Yii::setAlias('client', dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/client');`
- Open browser and access your desired directory `http://localhost/halodocnew/client/web/index.php`

I don't think it is sooper dooper solution but I used these methods =:)

Comment: I have tried. after i detemine choose solution which use .htaccess and urlManager